# Change/Add payload existing TCP packages?

Tags: python, regex, networking

I want to change the payload of all existing outgoing packets, so all packets that have "wordA" in it will be changed to "wordB", this will be done by a regex match.

I tried Python's scapy, but I don't know how to get it working.

PS: There won't be any wifi involved in here. Options that require port forwarding are depreciated.

Comment: What operating system?  It is rather unlikely you can do this without some kind of OS-level magic to shim python into the TX path of the ethernet interface

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
text = re.sub("\bwordA\b", "wordB", text)
```

Comment: text is not bound to outgoing packages, how does it suppose to work?